# Spigot: checking a message / commands sent by players or the console before sending / executing it

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

For my plugin I have to intercept messages and commands sent (msg or command ex: "*Hello word*" or "*/kill player1*") by players or the console and check it before sending / executing they.

Is there any way to do it?

I'm using Spigot 1.18.1

Answer (score 1):

You should use event. Firstly, register it in your `onEnable()` like that :

```java
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvent(new ManageChatAndCommandListener(), this);
```

## Manage messages

To manage message, you should use `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` ([Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/AsyncPlayerChatEvent.html)) like that :

```java
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
   if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("My not allowed message")) {
       e.setCancelled(true); // don't send the message
   }
}
```

## Manage commands

To manage commands, you should use `PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent` ([Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent.html)) like that :

```java
@EventHandler
public void onCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent e){
   if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("/not-allowed-command")) {
       e.setCancelled(true); // don't run the command
   }
}
```

Warn: the message correspond to the command, with the `/`. Even if most of people use `/`, you should just ignore the first char and not the `/` itself